# Lua Loop with error detection not working correctly

Tags: loops, lua

I scripted a simple bot program a week or two ago, and have been building on it with new knowledge as I broaden my understanding.

```
local B = 1 --Boss check 1 = true, 2 = false

repeat
  function bossCheck()
    local rgb1 = getColor(x,y)
    if rgb1 == (rgb) then
      touchDown(x,y)
      usleep(time)
      touchUp(x,y)
    end

    local D = 1 --Delay, corrective action when script is out of sync with loading times
    repeat
      if rgb1 ~= (rgb) then
        D = D + 1
        usleep(time)
      end
    until D == 5
  end
  if D == 5 then
    B = B + 1
  end
until B == 2

if B == 2 then
  alert("No Boss")
end
```

This actually worked in a loop until I added the correction check delay. If the `function bossCheck()` failed, then in my mind it should `repeat`. Am I wrong in assuming this is workable, or have I misplaced some loop statements?

Prior to this new code I implemented with `local D = 1 --for delay` I would attempt to touch at my IOS screen twice, it would return `not true` results and then my loop would end. But as of now, I run my script and nothing happens and it would appear that the script runs indefinately.

It's very confusing. I don't expect a verbatim line I should include here, but kind of hint me into the right direction.

Edit - Example

'function bossCheck ()
   if (getColor(x,y) == "color1") then
      return true;
   end
   return false;
end

function onBoss ()
   touch(x,y)
   usleep(time)
   return true;
end

function fightBoss ()
   touch(x2,y2)
   usleep(time)
   return true;
end

function bossReturn ()
   touch (x3,y3)
   usleep(time)
   return true;
end

function bossLoop ()
   while (bossCheck) do
      onBoss ();
      fightBoss ();
      bossReturn ();
   end
end

repeat
   bossLoop ();
until (bossCheck == false)

if (bossCheck == false) then
   alert("Boss Loop End")
end

'

Comment: From the code you posted, you defined a function `bossCheck`, but it's never called.

Comment: What is `rgb`? What is `rgb1` outside of the `bossCheck` function?

Comment: I still have a bit to learn about functions it would seem. From what I read, functions can be set locally in blocks, yes.

Comment: Rgb1 is just a string to call function `getColor` it helped with labeling them differently when I had 5 or so colorChecks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, `repeat until` executes the given script over and over until it reaches a statement.

Your script, re-define bossCheck as a function and checks if D equal to 5 (D is nil).

You do not call anywhere bossCheck, and because of that B remains 1.

This script should work.

```
local noBoss = false;
function bossCheck()
    noBoss = false;
    local rgb1 = getColor(x,y);
    if (rgb1 == rgb) then
      touchDown(x,y)
      usleep(time)
      touchUp(x,y)
      return -- if it's true, stop the function here;
    end
    noBoss = true;
    usleep(time * 5); -- no point delaying application action 5 times, when we call just multiply the sleep amount by 5;
end

repeat
    bossCheck();
until noBoss;

if (noBoss) then
    alert("No Boss");
end
```

**Edit:**

An example how I'd call several functions in sequence

```
function bossCheck()
    if (getColor(x,y) == rgb) -- instead doing rgb1= ..
        touchDown(x,y)
        usleep(time)
        touchUp(x,y)
        return true;
    end
    return false;
end
while true do
    if (not bossCheck()) then
        alert("No Boss");
        break; -- break out of the loop
    end
    if ((function () return true)()) then
        alert("This local function return true.. so alert message is shown\nYou can do the same with any other functions");
    end
end
```

According to your example you can just do this

```
function bossCheck()
    if (getColor(x,y) == rgb) -- instead doing rgb1= ..
        return true;
    end
    return false;
end

while true do
    if (bossCheck()) then
        touch(x,y)
        usleep(time)
        touch(x2,y2)
        usleep(time)
        touch(x3,y3)
        usleep(time)
    else
        alert("No Boss");
        break; -- break out of the loop
    end
end
```

Comment: So you can set any logic block to `function`? And when you call `until noBoss` this means to check if the statement had been changed to `=true`.

Comment: So this script worked, `if (noBoss) then` alerted me. Can I add `else` if the check returns `false` and there actually is a boss.

Comment: You can add else and print if there is an boss, though it will never be printed, because once you break the loop it means noBoss is true, so it'll alert 'no boss', to print that there is a boss, just add alert in the bossCheck function.

Comment: If the function returns `true`, it will `alert`. But if it is `false` and if it returns `false` it will keep looping until `alert("No Boss")`. How can add another function to call in sequence immediately after 'bossCheck`?

Comment: Added an example to OP not sure how to form code blocks while on mobile. But my question, would that code loop correctly?

Comment: Updated accroding to your example..
(no point creating functions for those actions if you don't use them more than once).

Comment: But theoretically if I set them to function, I could call them at any point in the loop if I set them to `(getColor)` and gave them all a `true if not false` and 'if false goto` value. That way the script could catch itself in a loop error and correct its position.

Comment: Or this could work perfectly for a loop with auto correction .. `function maxAttempts ()    for attempts = 1, 3, 1 do       print("attempt + " .. attempts)    if (attempts == 3) then          print("--save for goto label")       end    end end maxAttempts ();`. I would just have to call this between functions in the loop and set a local variable for each function inside of the loop. When this specific function gets called it would cycle through the loop until all functions return `(maxAttempts);` then the loop would `break`. Correct?